# Python explicit next() slower than a for loop in multithreaded producer-consumer paradigm

Tags: python, multithreading, generator

Suppose I have the following code that is runs for 10 iterations and calls the generator `gen_next_img_batch`:

```
for _ in get_next_img_batch(train_data_paths, classes, batch_size):
     pass
```

Now, suppose I replace it with the following, equivalent (to my mind) iteration:

```
for i in range(10):
    next(get_next_img_batch(train_data_paths, classes, batch_size))
```

The conundrum I have is that the first snippet takes 17 seconds, while the second takes 42 seconds. Moreover, every iteration of the second snippet takes *more* time than the previous iteration. That is, iteration i+1 of the second snippet takes longer than iteration i. All the iterations of the first snippet take the same time.

An important fact seems to be that the generator `gen_next_img_batch` that is iterated over takes data from a Python Queue that is constantly populated in a background thread. More specifically, in the background, a separate thread is loading data to a Queue, and every call to `next()` yields an object from that Queue. When this asynchronous behaviour is omitted, both snippets take the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not equivalent. Specifically, your first fragment calls `get_next_img_batch()` once, while your second calls that function 10 times. An equivalent fragment might be:

```
it = get_next_img_batch(train_data_paths, classes, batch_size))
for i in range(10):
    next(it)
```

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the trivial mistake. May I ask, however, why did the iteration times of the second snippet increase monotonically? Was it a function of the fact that due the increasing number of threads running in parallel, the system exhibited a general slowdown due to high CPU usage?